# How do Shaving Creams, Foams, Soaps ensure cut Hair Fragments that stick & clump between Safety Razor blades are easily washed away?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, green-chemistry

This is my first post on Chemistry SE and I figure it's pretty chemical oriented.

On [Sustainability SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/organic-natural-maybe-edible-alternatives-for-pre-shaving-cream-foam-oil-e/5331#5331) we were trying to find "organic & natural" alternatives which are okay for lubrication & moisturizing (don't really care about foaming etc), but so far we have one key problem:

Hair fragments clumping and getting stuck in between 3-4 blades of a safety razor and not easily washing out using water, which is not as much an issue with commercial shave products.

Is it some (one or more) active ingredients/chemicals that make it happen or some other chemical phenomenon by which this works?

Comment: The same clumping between the blades still happens with commercial shaving creams , I find that it always happens with cheap razors. Also depends how long the hair is too.

Comment: It washes out easier. Should I rephrase question and add that?

Comment: @Joel rephrased the question to point out that it's easily washed away whereas with natural products tried it wasn't so. So what're the active ingredients & phenomenon at play

Answer (score 1):

Active chemicals are called surfactants. It is well explained in colloid chemistry books and kind of in wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfactant)

And it is possible to find alternatives for such chemicals in nature, but they won't be as effective as artificial.

Comment: Could you improve/ detail more in your answer; list some of these inside Shave products and maybe some natural ones?